# Ajax/Jquery Form won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login form that is working in a kinda same way I don't know why this won't work. When I press 'Criar' it does nothing, it doesn't even change the text of that Button to 'Loading ...' as I have stated on beforeSend function. I started using Jquery so sorry if it is a stupid mistake!

Form

```
<form id="criarSubCategoria-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="criarCategoria.php" method="post">
    <div class="col col-lg-4">
      <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group margin-top-pq">
        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-criarSubCategoria" id="btn-criarSubCategoria">
              Criar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

click Function

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $("#btn-login").click(function(){}); // this one is working so I didn't put all the code here

    $("#btn-criarSubCategoria").click(function(){
        var data = $("#criarSubCategoria-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '../functions/criarCategoria.php',
            data : data,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#btn-criarSubCategoria").html('Loading ...');
            },
            success :  function(response){
                if(response.codigo == "1"){
                    $("#btn-criarSubCategoria").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'none')
                }else{
                    $("#btn-criarSubCategoria").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'block')
                    $("#mensagem").html('<strong>Erro! </strong>' + response.mensagem);
                }
          }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you checked your console to see what errors are popping up?

Comment: Nothing pops up on the console

Comment: error: function (xhr,status,error){ console.log(error)} add this and show the error please

Comment: I think you just only need to serialize input only. I means try this one var data = $("#criarSubCategoria-form input").serialize();

Comment: @sachinkumar, while you can do that, it is easier to target the form. As for instance in your example you would need to also include the selector for select elements, and the selector for textareas

Comment: Is your form / html dynamically added by chance? Also think about adding a [mcve] as there is obviously too much left out of your question to diagnose the problem

Comment: Tried the var still the same. No my form is not dynamically added. I added the error function and nothing pops up still. Im sorry i just started using Jquery

Comment: Please share the output of Console.log(response) statement. If this return nothing then ensure your click event handler working or not.

Comment: @sachinkumar nothing on my console, it means my event not even triggering?

Comment: Add alert or console to ensure the event handler add aler and also pass event.preventdefault().

Comment: @sachinkumar i added a console.log and when im on the Login page it shows but when im on this page it wont

Comment: @sachinkumar Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, line 1 ...? but on the login page it works why its giving me this error

Comment: Oh lol it was the import of the library im so stupid, it works now

Comment: Ohh dear jQuery is not define. Or use jQuery instead of $ will works

Comment: @sachinkumar put as answer if u want i will accept it...

Comment: Sure brother. @Brunaine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not define. Or use jQuery instead of $ will works.
Change 1st line

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#btn-criarSubCategoria", (function(e, $){
```

Comment: It help, Thanks Sachin!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your click function

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-criarSubCategoria", (function(e){
var data = $("#criarSubCategoria-form").serialize();
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : '../functions/criarCategoria.php',
    data : data,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function()
    {
        $("#btn-criarSubCategoria").html('Loading ...');
    },
    success :  function(response){
        if(response.codigo == "1"){
            $("#btn-criarSubCategoria").html('Entrar');
            $("#login-alert").css('display', 'none')
        }else{
            $("#btn-criarSubCategoria").html('Entrar');
            $("#login-alert").css('display', 'block')
            $("#mensagem").html('<strong>Erro! </strong>' + response.mensagem);
        }
  }
});
});
```

Hope this gets your work done.

Comment: Still the same, im updating my question i should've put maybe all the .js file, gimme a second

Comment: Are we supposed to compare line by line to see what you've changed? Please [edit] your answer to explain what the problem was and how your suggested code fixes it.

Comment: I have simply replaced .click function with .on('click') and added a ; after preventDefault() I am sorry but I am new to stackexchange so may be I don't know the answering ethics over here.

Comment: Don't forget to pass parathesis over click 
$(document).on("click", "#btn-criarSubCategoria", (function(e){